# Improving performance of creating multiple objects

Tags: c#, .net

I have the following code that creates objects:

```
foreach(string s in stringlist){
  AUser myuser = new AUser(s, "Employee");
  if(myuser.empid != null){
    userlist.Add(myuser);
  }
}
```

Each of the above steps are fairly quick but creating 10s of users starts taking a few seconds.  Is there a better way to do this?

-- EDIT --

Based on all of the answers, it's clear I should focus on the contructor.  Thanks because this is what I was looking for.   And yes - there is a lot going on in the contructor that can be optimized...and that will get time consuming.  Not sure how to accept the comment suggestions or an answer but that was all very helpful.

Comment: All I have in VS2010.  No other tools for performance testing.

Comment: I assume `new AUser()` is doing a database lookup for the employee with some property whose value is `s`? A little more information on what's underlying this code (especially the contents of the AUser constructor) would improve the quality of answers.

Comment: The only part of that code that could take a few seconds is the constructor for AUser but that's hard to believe.  Have you attempted to measure the performance accurately?

Comment: What does the constructor of the AUser class do?  I am guessing it queries a database or Active Directory, which is more than likely what is making this slow.  As @dario_ramos suggested, you need to get a better idea of what is taking so much time before we can help you.

Comment: What takes a long time? new? myuser.empid? or userlist.Add...

Comment: There is a lot of code missing here.  The AUser ctor, for one.

Comment: Just looking at this, I'm inclined to think your `AUser` constructor is the problem... instantiating your user collection should probably be done in a different manner.

Comment: "No other tools for performance testing" - if you have 'right' version of VS then you also have tools for profiling code. Or you can use http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=23205

Comment: Is the AUser constructor getting data from somewhere to populate the empid? Are there a significant number of these users that don't have an empid? If so, could you do a select ahead of time with the string list against the empid source to only have the list contain those items that have an empid?

Comment: Thanks on these comments.  It has helped me focus on one particular area - the constructor.

Answer (score 2):

When you're debugging, using F10 to step over the code, something that creates 10s of objects that takes a few seconds to run is almost unnoticeable. For example, let's say it creates 20 objects and takes 2 seconds to run. That means each object takes 1/10th of a second to be created. When pressing F10, it's hard for us as humans to notice 1/10th of a second. You also have to consider overhead of the attached debugger.

Try initializing a date variable just before creating the object, setting it to `DateTime.Now`. Then print out the elapsed time after creating the objects like `DateTime.Now.Subtract(someDate).TotalMilliseconds` to see where the problem lies. And, as @MikeNakis said if the `userList` variable has any extra code on top of being a normal`IList<>` then you should profile that as well.

There are other ways to profile, even built into the framework, but the DateTime method is the quick and easy route to find problems.

EDIT: Upvoted the question after I saw a -1 because it's a good example for the inexperienced to learn how to find performance issues.

Comment: +1 for the imperceptibility of performance bottlenecks while single-stepping.

Comment: Yes, good point. I'll also recommend [`Stopwatch` in System.Diagnostics](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch.aspx) as a fit-for-purpose alternative to `DateTime`.